# Under what conditions does $A \succeq B \succeq 0$ imply $A^2 \succeq B^2$?

Tags: operator-theory, matrix-analysis

For PSD matrices $A \succeq B \succeq 0$, I know that $t \mapsto t^2$ is not operator-monotone. Are there nice conditions under which we can still conclude that $A^2 \succeq B^2$?

Comment: Commutation ? otherwise can you find a counter example

Comment: Yes, if $A$ and $B$ commute then $A^2 \succeq B^2$.
I'm asking about more general conditions under which this is true.

Comment: This the known fact, $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&4\end{pmatrix}$ 

 $B=\begin{pmatrix}0.5&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$  (c. example)

Comment: Yes, I know that it's not true in general. What additional assumptions can we make on $A$ and $B$ so that it's true?

Comment: say $A\ge I$ and $B\le I$